# Update query in Access that sets the Status value equal for all record with the same ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am struggling to write an update query in Access that sets the Status value equal for all record with the same ID if Status contains a value.

The Table1 loooks like this now :

```
ID       Status
1
1          OK
2
2          OK
3
3
```

Wanted result is :

```
ID               Status
1                  OK
1                  OK  
2                  OK    
2                  OK
3
3
```

Comment: There's no picture... Add table definition, sample data and wanted result instead.

Comment: Sorry, but that's too little info to describe the problem. Edit your question. Add several rows with sample data, and also add the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access `UPDATE` queries can be finicky.  One which uses `GROUP BY` in a subquery will be treated as "not updatable".  You can use the [DMax()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835050.aspx) domain aggregate function to avoid that complaint ...

```sql
UPDATE tblOlaOkland AS y
SET y.Status = DMax('[Status]','[YourTable]','[ID]=' & y.ID)
WHERE
        y.Status Is Null
    AND DMax('[Status]','[YourTable]','[ID]=' & y.ID) Is Not Null;
```

Replace *YourTable* with the name of your table in both places.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery.  However, this is probably easier to express using `join`:

```
update table1 join
       (select id, max(status) as maxstatus
        from table1 as t
        group by id
       ) as t2
       on table1.id = t.id
    set table1.status = t2.maxstatus
    where t2.maxstatus is not null;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you for the reply. I’m new to Access and SQL, so do you know why I receive syntax error in the update code when I try to run the code you posted?